# Using dask to read data from Hive

Tags: pandas, hive, dask

I am using `as_pandas` utility from `impala.util` to read the data in `dataframe` form fetched from hive. However, using pandas, I think I will not be able to handle large amount of data and it will also be slower. I have been reading about dask which provides excellent functionality for reading large data files. How can I use it to efficiently fetch data from hive.

```
def as_dask(cursor):
"""Return a DataFrame out of an impyla cursor.
This will pull the entire result set into memory.  For richer pandas- 
like functionality on distributed data sets, see the Ibis project.

Parameters
----------
cursor : `HiveServer2Cursor`
    The cursor object that has a result set waiting to be fetched.
Returns
-------
DataFrame
"""
    import pandas as pd
    import dask
    import dask.dataframe as dd

    names = [metadata[0] for metadata in cursor.description]
    dfs = dask.delayed(pd.DataFrame.from_records)(cursor.fetchall(), 
    columns=names)
    return dd.from_delayed(dfs).compute()
```

Comment: Hi Ali. I am not quite sure what you are asking. Your question could read as if you are asking an opinion, and that is not ideal on this site (read the guidelines). You also don't have any code to demonstrate, to give responders a possibility to give you concrete, practical, usable help. maybe you could reformulate your question?

Comment: Thank you @JoSSte for your guidance. I have added the current code implementation for explanation.

Comment: How about `pyspark`? It can read Hive tables plus Spark DataFrames has `toPandas` method that can convert it to Pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no current straight-forward way to do this. You would do well to see the implementation of [dask.dataframe.read_sql_table](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/dask/dataframe/io/sql.py) and similar code in [intake-sql](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/intake-sql/blob/master/intake_sql/intake_sql.py) - you will probably want a way to partition your data, and have each of your workers fetch one partition via a call to `delayed()`. `dd.from_delayed` and `dd.concat` could then be used to stitch the pieces together.

-edit-

Your function has the delayed idea back to front. You are delaying and the immediately materialising the data within a function that operates on a single cursor - it can't be parallelised and will break your memory if the data is big (which is the reason you are trying this).

Lets suppose you can form a set of 10 queries, where each query gets a different part of the data; do **not** use OFFSET, use a condition on some column that is indexed by Hive.
You want to do something like:

```
queries = [SQL_STATEMENT.format(i) for i in range(10)]
def query_to_df(query):
    cursor = impyla.execute(query)
    return pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor.fetchall())
```

Now you have a function that returns a partition and has no dependence on global objects - it only takes as input a string.

```
parts = [dask.delayed(query_to_df)(q) for q in queries]
df = dd.from_delayed(parts)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added the current code snippet. Can you please guide me about the effect if use "dataframe.repartitions" option for making chunks after making it a delayed object.

Comment: Thank you @mdurant . Your answer helped me understanding how dask would work. You specifically mentioned not to use offset. I am finding it hard to come up with a condition on a column in Hive table. Any specific reason of not using **offset** ?

Comment: Offset will scroll through your data from the head of the table for every query, so you'll be causing the server to read most of your table for each partition you actually want. Normally you will have a sortable unique ID column to use for this, which is, ideally, indexed.