# Any Faster Alternative for Pandas Data Frame for HIVE Queries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hive

I am using the following query on hive

cur.execute('select * from table_name)

and getting the data into a pandas dataframe

output_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall(),columns=colname)

The tables that I run on generally have rows/entry records ranging from 1 Million to more than 80 Million and the code works fine for smaller tables but majority of my run time goes in to this step "output_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall(),columns=colname)"

For bigger tables (more than 4-5 Million entries) the code gets stuck or take hours of time

Is there any better alternative to improve the run time in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You could check out Dask, which is built on Pandas and handles large data in partitions. Try to cut your query in parts so you can assign different parts of the data to each dask worker. You can make a set of queries based on an index column in HIVE like this (all credits to [Using dask to read data from Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52875508/using-dask-to-read-data-from-hive)):

```
queries = [SQL_STATEMENT.format(i) for i in range(10)]
def query_to_df(query):
    cursor = impyla.execute(query)
    return pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor.fetchall())
```

Then use construct Dask dataframes like this:

```
parts = [dask.delayed(query_to_df)(q) for q in queries]
df = dd.from_delayed(parts)
```

The Dask documentation is really clear so check out: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/delayed.html