# Which separator to use in pandas/dask read csv when importing the table from hive?

Tags: python, pandas, hive, dask, dask-dataframe

I am trying to import a table from hive to python(jupyter) in form of dask dataframe from but it's not getting imported properly.So,can anyone help me with right separator in this case.Please refer the image.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52875508/using-dask-to-read-data-from-hive

Comment: Hi @Cuckoo, as it is mentioned in the link provided above, did you tried to use dask-sql? https://dask-sql.readthedocs.io/en/0.2.1/pages/data_input.html#load-hive-data